# Entidade filha não recebe seu id apos merge da entidade pai via @CascadeType

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho um problema quando adiciono uma entidade no banco de dados via Cascade. Depois do *update* da entidade `Aluno` a entidade Filha `NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira` não funciona corretamente.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ed44_aluno")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ED44_SQC", sequenceName = "ed44_aluno_ed44_cod_aluno_seq", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class Aluno implements AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ED44_SQC")
    @Column(name = "ed44_cod_aluno")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aluno", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira> linguas;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ed77_linguagem_aluno")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ED77_SQC", sequenceName = "s_ed77_linguagem_aluno", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira implements AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ED77_SQC")
    @Column(name = "ed77_cod_linguagem")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fked77ed44_cod_aluno")
    private Aluno aluno;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("post");      
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Aluno aluno = manager.find(Aluno.class, 1l);
        aluno.getLinguas().size();
        manager.close();

        NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira nivel = new NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira();
        nivel.setAluno(aluno);
        aluno.addLingua(nivel);

        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.merge(aluno); //update
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();

        System.out.println(nivel); // nivel.getId() == null WHY?
    }
```

Meu output:

> after find method call:
>   select aluno where id = 1 (edited, long query)

Depois de chamar o método `merge`:

> select nextval ('s_ed77_linguagem_aluno')

Depois do *commit*:

> insert into ed77_linguagem_aluno (fked77ed44_cod_aluno, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_ent, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_esc,>>fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_fal, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_le, >> fked77tg33_cod_lingua, ed77_cod_linguagem) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Fim do código:

> NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira [id=null, aluno=Aluno [id=1, codigoInep=null, codigoNis=null, nome=FULANO DE TAL EDITADO 8, apelido=null, nascimento=null, nDependentes=null, mae=null, pai=null, conjuge=null, fotoSrc=null, dataCadastro=2014-05-23 15:46:43.586, endereco=null, contato=null, documentacao=null], lingua=null, escreve=null, entende=null, fala=null, leitura=null]

O problema é que minha entidade `NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira` não recebe o seu id. Isso é ruim visto que se eu chamar o metodo MERGE novamente ele vai adicionar NOVAMENTE um `NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira` (porque ele não tem um ID, e pro JPA é um novo objeto).

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Olhando para seu código, acho que está correto.

Porém sugiro uma alteração:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("post");      
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    Aluno aluno = manager.find(Aluno.class, 1l);
    aluno.getLinguas().size();
    manager.close();

    NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira nivel = new NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira();
    nivel.setAluno(aluno);
    aluno.addLingua(nivel); // Não é necessário.

    manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.merge(nivel); //insert
    manager.getTransaction().commit();

    // ou, caso queria o objeto atualizado.
    aluno = manager.refresh(aluno);

    manager.close();

    System.out.println(nivel); // nivel.getId() == null WHY?
}
```

Nesse caso, acredito que o ORM irá realizar as inserções corretamente dado que o mapeamento `OneToOne` está na classe `NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira`, ele irá fazer a inserção da chave estrangeira `fked77ed44_cod_aluno` corretamente.

O fato dele não setar o ID está correto, dado que você só deu merge no `aluno`. Talvez um [`refresh`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29), na entidade `nivel` em seu código possa resolver o problema.